# SAQ D PCI Compliance for Custom Shopping Cart

Tags: pci-dss, e-commerce

We use a custom developed open-source e-commerce software. We are SAQ D and I am trying to figure out which of [these requirements](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_D_v3_Merchant.pdf) applies to our cart if:

1. We aren't storing credit card information
2. We transmit credit card information from the user to our server via TLS 1.2 and from our server to the payment gateway via TLS 1.2

I understand there is a boatload of networking, hosting, and process requirments that need to be met, but what specifically is required of a custom shopping cart?

Comment: My understanding is that SAQ C is not ever applicable to ecommerce merchants: https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/our-thinking/pci-compliance-which-saq-is-right-for-me/